# Connecting using jconsole to a java process without jmx parameters

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I have a java program in a weird condition where it has stopped running a certain thread.

I would like to connect to it using JMX, but I didn't provide the JMX arguments.

I could restart but then I would loss the information of the current condition.

I know that on Windows it can connect with jconsole on localhost without parameters, but my java app is running on a Linux server.

So any ideas on how to still be able to connect even without jmx parameters?

Comment: Depending on your JDK version, there is a diagnostic command called that enables you to start the remote JMX agent on a running JVM. Run jcmd <pid> help ManagementAgent.start to see how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JConsole works on linux also. If the linux server have xhost or some remote displaying capability, I would just run jconsole on the linux server.

If you didn't enable JMX when the java program was started, you would not be able to connect remotely via JMX.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is an option to dump the threads:

kill 3

Used it and found the reason.

Thank you.